# What is a part in the youtube api v3, and how should I use it

Tags: youtube-api

I was trying to make the "try it now" work on the youtube api page in this link:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#try-it
What do I need to write in each text box?
It is very unclear for a noob like me...
The explanation about what a part is is very unclear. What a property is, where should I use these. There are no examples of usage. It is very frustrating.
As a side note - this whole API documentation is as if written for someone who already knows how to use it.. very unfriendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic explanations are right next to each text box: more details can be found on the API Overview page, under [Partial Resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#partial).

`part`: The part parameter specifies the `videoCategory` resource parts that the API response will include Supported values are id and snippet.
Type in `id`, `snippet`, or `id, snippet`.

`regionCode`: instructs the API to return the list of video categories available in the specified country. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. Type in `us` or your country code.

Click the 'Execute' button to get results.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0"

Next, in addition to entering id and snippet (The "bold red = required") you must provide at least one filter such as 'us' or your country code in the regionCode.  Rather than give a bad request the instructions probably should have indicated that at least one filter is required.  The automatically generated request should then show as something like:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=us&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And you should see a response starting with something like:

```
200 OK 
- Show headers -  
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/ktNNfqmO8tgQADyscLhmrqfzsa4\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_mzWJs/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
   "id": "1",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation",
    "assignable": true
   }
  },
```